# How to get most popular data from user query results in Apache Solr?

Tags: php, caching, solr, filter

I have configuration
**schema.xml**:

```
<field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required=" multiValued="false" />
<field name="name" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
<defaultSearchField>name</defaultSearchField>

<fieldType name="text_vi" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" sortMissingLast="true">
    <analyzer type="index">...
    <analyzer type="query">...
</fieldType>
```

In my application, user can search by field 'name'. Now, I want to get most popular data from user query results.

Can anyone explain the procedure step by step and provide example also?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: What do you mean by "most popular data from user query results" According the number of clicks on a single result? Or the most frequently searched terms?

Comment: I meant most frequently "results", not "searched terms". Tks

Answer (score 0):

Solr doesn't provide any out of the box feature as such. You might take a look at [statscomponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent) for index stats. 
If you trying to develop autocomplete features at term level then look at [termscomponent](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Terms+Component), which provides top terms with number of matches.
Top matching result you can sort using count-

```
q=search_text:xyz&wt=json&indent=on&rows=50&sort=count desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try boosting the result like this

```
name:marco ^2
```

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ